# Error MVC5: Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una aplicación en MVC 5 que utiliza un componente para validar la session pero me esta generando este error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ExternalURL/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Es porque se esta tratando de solicitar una dirección de dominio diferente. Como puedo habilitar para que no me siga mandando este mensaje.

PD: el mensaje lo manda el navegador y  no me permite hacer solicitudes ajax al controlador.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque la solución escapa al desarrollador, es decir, las modificaciones tienen que ser de un tercero, a quien contactar es imposible.

Answer (score 1):

**Opción A**: Si solamente vas a dar chance a ciertas páginas, en el controlador agregar a tu `POST`, `GET` u otro verbo que utilices:

```
HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

**Opción B**: Modifica el `web.config` y le provees acceso a toda la aplicación:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Y por motivos de seguridad, agrega el `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]` a tus `Actions` y en tus formularios : `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`.

Comment: Agregue lo siguiente en le web.config de mi aplicacion <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol> y sigue mandando  el mismo error, la dll que utilizo para la session lo descompile y esta realizando un redireccionamiento de esta manera HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(ruta)

Comment: eres dueño de ese dominio diferente?

Comment: No, el dominio diferente, es de otros desarrolladores y dudo que quieran modificar algo debido a que se esta usando en otras aplicaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que habilitar CORS

[Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

si se trata de servicio webapi simplemente en el register

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
     config.EnableCors();

     //resto codigo
```

Tambien podrias evaluar de configurarlo

[How to enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing in MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-in-mvc1)

en este caso agregas esto en el web.config

[CORS on ASP.NET](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html)

Comment: Buena tarde agregue lo siguiente el en web.config y continua con el error,   <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders> ya habia intentado agregar microsoft.aspnet.cors y no se resolvio el problema

Comment: que tipo de servicio estas exponiendo? son webapi o simples controllers de asp.net mvc. Recuerda que esto se define en el config del servicio no en tu codigo que actuaria de cliente

Comment: Estoy utilizando una DLL de otros desarrolladores que utilizan HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(ruta) cuando no se tiene iniciada la sesión, la utilizo en una aplicacion MVC. Lo que intento hacer es corregir este error desde mi aplicación que actúa como cliente.

Comment: no se puede solucionar desde tu aplicarion CORS lo debe habilitar el servidor. Debes solicutar a quien provee el servicio que modifique el codigo habilitando CORS, es justamente un tema de seguridad que viene por quien expone la funcionalidad, si tu como cliente podria cambiar esto entonces no tendria ninguna sentido